# Where are the pre-defined keyboards defined?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

When installing Ubuntu, or when running
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
I get a list of pre-set keyboard layouts to choose from.

From where are these keyboard pre-layouts read? Where can I find the pre-sets for this list of keyboard layouts? I ask, because I assume that these settings are valid even outside of X, which means it's not in the `xkb` settings. Am I correct, or am I mistaken?

Also, this list is not exhaustive (as I can't find the one I am using), so I assume they must have been added as pre-set layouts at some point. What is the process to add a new such pre-set layout?
(I know that I can re-map keys in the `xkb` settings, but this is not what I am asking here.)

**Edit** I find there are keyboard layouts in
`/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/`
but I don't see a full overlap. There are geometries there whose names I cannot find in the list, and vice versa. Tampering with these layouts do produce the wished-for result, though. I guess there must be some other file where the keyboard names and their respective files are defined.

Comment: Please post the location as an answer.

Comment: I found them in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/`  However, there is not a full name overlap in titles. So there must be some place where the keyboard layouts to be loaded to the list are named, and their filenames stated. I can edit the files in `/geometry` and the result are immediately reflected, even without a reboot. So I guess the settings do lie in `xkb` after all. But I cannot change the names of the keyboards, and I cannot seem to enter a new one myself.

Comment: Is your question solved?

Comment: Partly. I still don't know where the list is defined. It doesn't seem as if the system simply reads the `/geometry` folder and lines up everything it finds there -- the keyboard names don't match. This must be specified someplace else, and I have not found that.

Comment: And... I found that aswell. That list lies in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` So yes, the question is solved. At least for the moment.

Comment: Is it the list of keyboard models you are talking about (which is something different than keyboard layouts)?

Comment: If phrased like that, I guess it's a model. When you run a keyboard-reconfiguration, you get a list of keyboards, sorted after name. None of the keyboards there match the keyboard I have. But I've found where they are defined, and it was not hard to tinker with those files.

Comment: Correction: I did not find it exactly. The list in base.lst and evdev.lst do indeed look as if they are lists of the keyboard layouts that you get with a `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, but editing those files does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `/etc/default/keyboard` file.

[Here](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/configure-keyboard-ubuntu/) you can find a short explanation about keyboard-preferences.

Comment: That link contains only information on how to change what language the selected keyboard is defined for. What I asked for was that list he shows, of all the keyboard layouts, where all those are defined. But I found it, as per my comments above. What is strange is that he also claims that any changes made in `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` will not survive a reboot. For me, they do. At least the keyboard layout changes stay after a reboot.